# Use jQuery to find previous occurence of class in Dom Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screen-scraping

I'd like to get returned an Object of the previous occurrence of a class in a portion of the Dom Tree and if there is no previous occurrence then I want to be told so.

Definition of previous occurrence: The previous occurrence of "21ld" from $(this) within the each cycles - basically where you would find it, when textsearching the entire ".window" classes source code backwards for "21ld" from $(this).

html (very, very simplified, the actual structure is very chaotic and unpredictable):

```
<div class='window'>

    <div class='093a'>
          <div class='a9a3'>
                <div class='21ld'></div>
         </div>
         <div class='99l1'>
                <div class='uuu99l1'>
                    <div class='saved'></div>
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='i93d'>
          <div class='ad9l3'>
                <div class='ool1ld'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='j93d'>
          <div class='aid9l3'>
                <div class='okl1ld'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='a93d'>
          <div class='9l3'>
                <div class='21ld'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='rbl1'> 
         <div class='4l1'>
                <div class='saved'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class='r0l1'> 
         <div class='0adl1'>
                <div class='0l1'>
                      <div class='21ld'></div>
                </div>
         </div
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.window').find('.21ld').each(function(index){
      console.log($(this).fromHereFindPreviousOccurence('.saved'));
});
```

so I expect an output of:

```
1: undefined/false/whatever
2: jQuery Object of first saved class from my example
3: jQuery Object of second saved class from my example
```

I'd be really happy if someone could help me out here? :)

Comment: why do you want to do this? i think the answer here is going to be pretty complicated and may have to involve traversing the entire DOM each time you're looking for a class

Comment: "previous" as written in your HTML doesn't mean the same thing as previous in the DOM tree.  I don't think you're going to be able to do this as written.  But as @Cruiser said, if you tell us WHY you want to do this, we might help you plan a better solution.

Comment: another function saves elements from the dom and in this function i need a data value from the last ".saved" element going backwards from the elements in the each cycles in the source.

Comment: and what we're really asking, when we say why do you want to do this, is what is the original problem that you're trying to solve by getting this info.  not just what is the previous step/function in your solution that calls this.

Comment: i'm scraping individual elements from a conversation thread - the chaotic html structure is the entire conversational thread - i'm picking out certain parts and saving them, then marking them as saved by adding the class. then on update of this thread, i want to know if $(this) in the each cycle happened after a ".save" class in the entire thread and if so, i want to get data from the found instance of the class.

Comment: but it's not clear what you mean by "after", in that comment.  Surely replies to reply #1 might have happened either before or after replies to reply #2, timewise.  What's your goal?

Comment: @andi - okay, first: i'm not saving replies, i'm only saving individual parts of text like "<span class='.saved'></span>" and they can be anywhere on the page - and then sometimes another person or the same person can say something where a portion of the text has the class "21ld" - so with my code i want to correlate on user click every 21ld to its previous occurence of saved within the scope of the entire message thread

Comment: I don't understand any of that last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will traverse the DOM to find the previous save.  It will only work if the structure remains the same.  If there is some rhyme or reason to the parent `div` class names then you could write it a little better.

```js
var $window = $('.window'),
  //immediate div children
  $parentContainers = $('.window > div');

$window.find('.21ld').each(function() {
  var $currentElement = $(this),
    $prevSave;

  $parentContainers.each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this),
      parentContainer = $(this).find($currentElement).length > 0,
      $innerSave = $this.find('.saved');

    if (parentContainer) {
      //breaks out of iteration if we've found the current element
      return false;
    } else if ($innerSave.length > 0) {
      //cache the most recent save elemen
      $prevSave = $innerSave;
    }
  });

  var text = typeof $prevSave === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : $prevSave.text(),
    parent = typeof $prevSave === 'undefined' ? '' : ' in ' + $prevSave.parent().attr('class')

  //shows results using the parent class names
  console.log($currentElement.parent().attr('class') + ' found ' + text + parent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='window'>
  <div class='093a'>
    <div class='a9a3'>
      <div class='21ld'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='99l1'>
      <div class='uuu99l1'>
        <div class='saved'>first save</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='i93d'>
    <div class='ad9l3'>
      <div class='ool1ld'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='j93d'>
    <div class='aid9l3'>
      <div class='okl1ld'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='a93d'>
    <div class='9l3'>
      <div class='21ld'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='rbl1'>
    <div class='4l1'>
      <div class='saved'>second save</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='r0l1'>
    <div class='0adl1'>
      <div class='0l1'>
        <div class='21ld'></div>
      </div>
    </div </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you hit my problem right in the eye ;) my biggest problem is that there can be a dynamic number of parents above $(this) and I never know how many levels to go up. the class names are also different every time and so are the levels where .saved and 21ld are nested, by class name i could only traverse up to ".window" at which point i would have completely lost track of where i was coming from.

Comment: I updated the code in my question to reflect that a little

Comment: @Jessica Updated the snippet for you.  It could be optimized better, but I can't spend much time on it at the moment.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've used jQuery, but I just tested this and I think it should work.

**EDIT**: I realize this doesn't necessarily return the closest instance every time. In order to achieve what you want, you're actually going to have to expand your definition of previous or closest because once you walk up the tree a certain distance, the element that is closest to the other element becomes somewhat relative definitionally.

```
function findClass(el, needle) {
    let element = el

    while (element.nodeName !== 'HTML') {

        if ($(element).find(needle).length) {
            return $(element).find(needle)
        }

        element = element.parent()
    }
}
```

Comment: i added a definition, the actual dom tree is too complicated for something like that to properly work and i always need the previous (as in previous word in a text) occurrence

Comment: @Jessica I see what you're getting at, and starting with something like the above, or a recursive function of some sort is the direction you are going to want to go, but given relation "closeness", you are probably going to end up wanting to find the *last* instance of a class once you get a certain distance from the origin node.

Answer (score 0):

So you could use `.prev()`. [jQuery reference.](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) The JS would look something like this:

```
$(window).each('.21ld', function (i){
    var saved =$(this).prev('.saved');
    console.log(saved);
    if(saved.length < 0){
        console.log('.saved not found on occurance: ' + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not going to work in my use case, because $(this) can be in a completely place than the .saved class - they are both only in ".window" other than that they are in completely different trees